# How to get two Primefaces elements like MeterGaugeChartModel next to each other?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've got two `MeterGaugeChartModel` from Primefaces. Currently one is underneath the other, but I want them to get next to each other. How can I do that?

```
<p:panel header="Capacity Charts">
  <p:meterGaugeChart id="CPUchart" value="#{chartBean.meterGaugeModelCPU}"
                     showTickLabels="false" labelHeightAdjust="110" intervalOuterRadius="130"
                     seriesColors="66cc66, 93b75f, E7E658, cc6666" style="width:400px;height:250px"
                     title="CPU" label="percentage (%)"/>
  <p:meterGaugeChart id="RAMchart" value="#{chartBean.meterGaugeModelRAM}"
                     showTickLabels="false" labelHeightAdjust="110" intervalOuterRadius="130"
                     seriesColors="66cc66, 93b75f, E7E658, cc6666"
                     style="width:400px;height:250px"
                     title="RAM" label="percentage (%)"/>
</p:panel>
```

Comment: Why not just place them both in an `<h:panelGrid columns="2/>"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the solution that @kolossus proposes. On the [showcase website of Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf) you can find many examples of such an solution, like the [first example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprUpdate.jsf).

```
<p:panel header="Capacity Charts">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <p:meterGaugeChart id="CPUchart" ... />
        <p:meterGaugeChart id="RAMchart" ... />
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
```

This will add all child elements of the `panelGrid` to the next column. So adding another `<p:meterGaugeChart />` will add it to the first column of the row below.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, @kolossus proposes an excellent JSF-style solution: enclose your components in a panel grid. I would have done it that way as well.

If you don't want any *extra* JSF components you can use a very simple CSS: add `float:left` to both meter gauge components and add an extra `<div style="clear:both">`:

```
<p:panel header="Capacity Charts">
    <p:meterGaugeChart id="CPUchart" style="float:left;" ... />
    <p:meterGaugeChart id="RAMchart" style="float:left;" ... />
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</p:panel>
```